# impact of index on multiple where clause SQL

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table that contains 3-400k entries.

I want to do a prefix check on `ABCDEFABCDEFAB. (= A, = AB..)`
I have the index created 
  table.IDX: non-unique hash index on columns:

```
TYPE
INFORMATION
MATCH_PATTERN
MATCH_TYPE
```

I noticed that the sql request below does not use the index created. 
Is it the case? Any documentation relating to this?

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    table
                WHERE     table.type = 'TYPE'
                AND     table.info = 'INFO'
                AND     table.match_type = 'Prefix' 
       AND     (table.match_pattern like 'ABCDEFABCDEFAB%' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCDEFAB' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCDEFA' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCDEF' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCDE' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCD' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABC' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDEFAB' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDEFA' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDEF' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCDE' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABCD' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'ABC' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'AB' OR
                table.match_pattern = 'A');



create table aTable (
  SERIAL             INTEGER,
  NAME        CHAR(30),
  TYPE        CHAR(32),
  INFORMATION CHAR(32),
  MATCH_PATTERN      CHAR(40),
  MATCH_TYPE         TINYINT,
  primary key (SERIAL),
  foreign key (NAME) references nameTable(name));
create unique index NS.IDX 
ON aTable(NAME, TYPE, INFORMATION, MATCH_PATTERN, MATCH_TYPE);
```

Comment: Try switching your index columns, the order is important. `TYPE, info, MATCH_TYPE, MATCH_PATTERN`. Also `information` has a different name than in the query.

Comment: Just a short question: How many of the records are NOT MATCHING the above criteria? Because if it's not too much or not more than 50-60% of all raws ,then the query optimiser will choose a table scan.

Comment: Please provide `DDL + execution plan`

Comment: @Devart    
   Check above

Comment: Don't see execution plan... :(

Answer (score 0):

This will make use of the index, it's ugly but should perform well:

```
SELECT SUM(CNT) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern like 'ABCDEFABCDEFAB%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCDEFAB'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCDEFA'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCDEF'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCDE'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABCD'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDEFABC'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDEFAB'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDEFA'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDEF'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCDE'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABCD'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'ABC'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'AB'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table
  WHERE type = 'TYPE' AND info = 'INFO' AND match_type = 'Prefix' AND
        match_pattern = 'A'
) x;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!